# Trying to redirect output of shell script to file and stdout.  cd command in the script causes weird behaviour

Tags: java, file, shell, cd

Here is the situation:

I have a shell script - script.ksh

I am calling it from a java program and I need the stdout from the script in the java program.

I also need to redirect the output to a file and if the script fails at any point, I have to send a mail with the file attached to it.

so the file must be closed before the script exits so that the mailer can send it.

I have got everything working right.

Except for 1 thing - if there is any 'cd' statement in the script the file doesn't get closed before the script ends. Please help me out here

Not sure why this is happening.

Here's a simplified version of the code.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Need to redirect output to file and stdout
exec 6>&1  #save stdout in [6]
exec 1>shell.log 2>&1  #redirect stderr and stdout to file


#if any error happens reset stdout and print the log contents
trap '
echo "Error Trap";
exec 1>&- 1>&6 6>&-;
echo | cat shell.log>&1;
echo "send the log file by mail";
exit 1' ERR

#cd / #Uncomment and the script behaves differently
echo "some task"
./somescript.ksh   #this requires me to cd to its directory and then execute

trap - ERR  #End the ERR trap


#in case of normal exit print the log contents
trap '

echo "Normal Exit"
exec 1>&- 1>&6 6>&-;
echo | cat shell.log>&1;
exit 1' EXIT
```

Comment: built in commands have problems when executed from java... probably your problem is around that...

Comment: I do not get any different results when i execute from prompt or java. behaviour changes if i comment the cd command

Answer (score 1):

You are opening files in the current directory and then changing directories. Try using absolute paths for those files.

Why are you piping `echo` through `cat`? It has no effect in your script. Just `cat` the file. There's no need to redirect stdout to stdout either. `cat file` is the same as `cat file >&1`.

Why are you doing `exit 1` for a normal exit. I should be `exit 0`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the exit and echo cat mistakes. 

using absolute paths does work. But I can't really use absolute paths since i'm calling another script from my script, and the other script uses relative paths. and I can't change the other script.

If there is any simple workaround then please tell otherwise I have got a workaround at the java end. but if i could just make the cd work the way i want it would save me lot of work...

is this problem being caused by subshells being created by cd? Thats what google results point to.

Comment: @Sougata: I assume you can't change the other script. If that's the case, then you need to specify a full absolute path to `shell.log`. `cd` doesn't create any subshells. You're just in a different directory than where you started and you're trying to close a file that's not in the new directory. Try using `pushd` instead of `cd` then you can do `popd` right before you close the file in the trap and at the end. Also, it's not necessary to set an `EXIT` trap right before you exit - just execute those commands directly.